# coding conditional flow netlogo between 3 nodes in network diffusion model

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create conditional flow between nodes in netlogo. Using the code from the diffusion model, I am trying to set it up that if turtle 1 has a value greater than x (e.g.  1), the current flow from turtle 1 stops flowing into turtle 2. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code that I have currently.

```
`directed-link-breed [active-links active-link]
undirected-link-breed [inactive-links inactive-link]

turtles-own [ val new-val ] ; a node's past and current quantity, represented as size
links-own [ current-flow ]  ; the amount of quantity that has passed through a link
                            ; in a given step

globals [
  total-val                 ; total quantity in the system
  max-val                   ; maximum quantity held by a single node in the system
  max-flow                  ; maximum quantity that has passed through a link in the system
  mean-flow                 ; average quantity that is passing through an arbitrary
                            ; link in the system
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Setup Procedures ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to setup
  clear-all
   set-default-shape turtles "circle"

  create-turtles 3 [set color blue]

  ask turtle 0 [setxy -11 16]
  ask turtle 1 [setxy -12 8]
  ask turtle 2 [setxy -9 12]


 ask turtle 0 [
    set val 1
    create-active-link-to turtle 2
    [set current-flow 1]
  ]



  ask turtle 1 [
    set val 1
    create-active-link-to turtle 2
  [set current-flow 1]
]

 ask turtle 2 [
    set val 1
    create-active-link-to turtle 0
  [set current-flow 1]
]

 ask turtle 2[
    set val 1
    create-active-link-to turtle 1
  [set current-flow 1]
]

  update-globals
  update-visuals
  reset-ticks
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Main Procedure  ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to go
  ask turtles [ set new-val 0 ]
  ask turtles [
    let recipients out-active-link-neighbors
    ifelse any? recipients [
      let val-to-keep val * (1 - diffusion-rate / 100)
      ; we keep some amount of our value from one turn to the next
      set new-val new-val + val-to-keep
      ; What we don't keep for ourselves, we divide evenly among our out-link-neighbors.
      let val-increment ((val - val-to-keep) / count recipients)
      ask recipients [
        set new-val new-val + val-increment
        ask in-active-link-from myself [ set current-flow val-increment ]
      ]
    ] [
      set new-val new-val + val
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [ set val new-val ]

  update-globals
  update-visuals
  tick
end



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;     Updates     ;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to update-globals
  set total-val sum [ val ] of turtles
  set max-val max [ val ] of turtles
  if any? active-links [
    set max-flow max [current-flow] of active-links
    set mean-flow mean [current-flow] of active-links
  ]
end

to update-visuals
  ask turtles [ update-node-appearance ]
  ask active-links [ update-link-appearance ]
end

to update-node-appearance ; node procedure
  ; scale the size to be between 0.1 and 5.0
  set size 0.1 + 5 * sqrt (val / total-val)
end

to update-link-appearance ; link procedure
  ; scale color to be brighter when more value is flowing through it
  set color scale-color gray (current-flow / (2 * mean-flow + 0.00001)) -0.4 1
end
`
```

Comment: Do you specifically mean those turtle numbers (so 2 is somehow responsible for the flow between 1 and 3) or are you asking a more generic question about `if` statements? Also, there is no turtle 3, they are numbered 0, 1 and 2

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, turtles are 0 1 and 2. In this example, I would like to set it up that if turtle 1 has value going into turtle 2, then the flow from turtle 0 into turtle 2 stops. I tried a 'hide-link' function to mimic this but it appears that my if statement was incorrect.

Comment: `hide-turtle` simply makes the link invisible. If you won't need the flow in the future, you can do something like `if .... ask link turtle 0 turtle 1 [die]`. You really need to show us the relevant code rather than the model without the code. For example, you say that you have tried `hide-turtle` but I can't see it in the above code.

Comment: Hello, the if statement that you proposed got the wheels turning and I solved the issue. I'm new to netlogo thus, the syntax is still challenging. Here is the line of code with the if statement included. 

`ask turtle 2
    [
      if total-val > 1 [ask in-link-from turtle 0 [die]     
      ]
       ]`

Thank you for your help